# Can we transfer energy wirelessly?

Tags: energy, solar-cells

Now-a-days solar energy is good alternating source of energy and it is free without any harmful effect to our environment. But earth based solar energy systems are dependent on a major factor, which is of weather. One need a clear sky, in most of the days throughout the year to utilize solar power. If we establish a solar energy system in space then we can harvest this energy without any disturbance from weather. The question is, the power generated in such a station, can we transfer it to earth from space wirelessly? Is it possible?

Comment: with EM waves of frequencies able to go through clouds and compatible with down devices ?

Comment: I'm unconvinced this is a physics question rather than an engineering question. [EM waves transmit power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector) so in principle we just send some suitable EM wave down to a receiving station on the surface. Questions about how to do this and whether the weather would interfere seem to me to be about engineering.

Comment: And it isn't like ideas of space-based solar arrays, and the issues with energy transfer, haven't been around for ... (thinks) ... well, at least 50 years in science fiction, and 40 or more as semi-serious engineering studies.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible (laser, microwave, ...), and experimented. Not without problems: avoiding absorption, diffusion, and trying not to burn the floor on a too large area :-) (caused by diffraction, zthmospheric perturbations, possibly errors...) . Note also that you might send reload hi-capacity batteies. Does it count ? ;-)